# Undefined variable : function parameter (PHP)

Tags: php, function, post, undefined, function-parameter

I'am newbie with PHP and i have a issue with my php form validation that return this error, if the username and the password are not defined.

Notice: Undefined variable: username in D:\hpsp\controller\loginvalidation.inc.php on line 64

I use 2 functions (usernameValidation & passwordValidation) to check if $_POST input are correct or not but i don't know what's and where i have to put the correct script, Thank you in advance.

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('../model/pdo.inc.php');
// function for checking the username validation (not empty & Regex)
function usernameValidation($username) // Username as parameter
{
if ( !empty($_POST['username']) )
{
    $username = strtolower(htmlspecialchars($_POST['username'])); // username will be tranform to lowercase before regex matching

    if ( preg_match('#^[a-z0-9\.]{5,20}$#', $username) ) //  5 <= username lenght <= 20 in lowercase character to be valid
    {
        return true; // return true when the username is valid
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Invalid username, please re-try" ;
    }
}
else
{
    echo "Enter your username";
}
}

// function for checking the password validation (not empty & Regex)
function passwordValidation($password) // Password as parameter
{
if ( !empty($_POST['password']) )
{
    $password = htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']) ; // Protect the password

    if ( preg_match('#^[a-zA-Z0-9\.-_@$()]{6,10}$#', $password) ) // 6 <= password length <= 10 character to be valid
    {
        return true; // return true when password is valid
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "Invalid password, please re-try";   
    }
}
else
{

    echo "Enter your password";    
}
}


if ( usernameValidation($username) == true AND passwordValidation($password) == true )
{
// PDO Query (SELECT ...)
}
```

Comment: To put your parameter as optional, you need to put it like that : `functionName($var='default')`

Comment: `$username` Where do you have this variable defined in your script? :)

Comment: try to echo $_POST['username']  and check either it have some value or not?

Comment: You are initializing $username in usernameValidation. Because this is a function the $username variable can't be called upon outside of that function. You will need to define $username outside of the function usernameValidation() to make it work.

Comment: use if ( usernameValidation($_POST['username']) == true AND passwordValidation($POST['password']) == true )

Comment: At your case both function must not have any param in them usernameValidation($username) > usernameValidation() you catch data directly from POST's which is wrong but you have to think how to change it ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this (note you never want to echo out individual messages for email and password to stop hackers gaining information about which is correct:

```
session_start();
require_once('../model/pdo.inc.php');

//username and password will contain the posted resulte or FALSE
$username = usernameValidation();
$password = passwordValidation();
if (!$username OR !$password) {
    echo 'Invalid username or password!';
    die;
}
// PDO Query (SELECT ...)

// function for checking the username validation (not empty & Regex)
function usernameValidation() { // Username as parameter
    if (!empty($_POST['username'])) {
        $username = strtolower(htmlspecialchars($_POST['username'])); // username will be tranform to lowercase before regex matching

        if (preg_match('#^[a-z0-9\.]{5,20}$#', $username)) { //  5 <= username lenght <= 20 in lowercase character to be valid
            return $username; // return true when the username is valid
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}

// function for checking the password validation (not empty & Regex)
function passwordValidation() { // Password as parameter
    if (!empty($_POST['password'])) {
        $password = htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']); // Protect the password

        if (preg_match('#^[a-zA-Z0-9\.-_@$()]{6,10}$#', $password)) { // 6 <= password length <= 10 character to be valid
            return $password; // return true when password is valid
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: You are right naw103 i was focused on give the user which right username or password, but for security reason I'll take this note into consideration.

Comment: Can i ask you a question, why i shouldn't give a parameter to the function?

Comment: You dont need to pass the username into the function since you were already getting the data from the POST inside those functions and hence I saw the functions job as getting the username for you (as well performing validation etc)

Answer (score 0):

Define your functions withow arguments

```
function usernameValidation(){ ... }
```

and call it

```
if ( usernameValidation() == true AND passwordValidation() == true )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 session_start();
require_once('../model/pdo.inc.php');
// function for checking the username validation (not empty & Regex)
function usernameValidation($username) // Username as parameter
{
if ( !empty($_POST['username']) )
{
$username = strtolower(htmlspecialchars($_POST['username'])); // username will be tranform to lowercase before regex matching

if ( preg_match('#^[a-z0-9\.]{5,20}$#', $username) ) //  5 <= username lenght <= 20 in lowercase character to be valid
{
    return true; // return true when the username is valid
}
else
{
    echo "Invalid username, please re-try" ;
}
}
else
{
echo "Enter your username";
}
}

// function for checking the password validation (not empty & Regex)
function passwordValidation($password) // Password as parameter
{
if ( !empty($_POST['password']) )
{
$password = htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']) ; // Protect the password

if ( preg_match('#^[a-zA-Z0-9\.-_@$()]{6,10}$#', $password) ) // 6 <= password length <= 10 character to be valid
{
    return true; // return true when password is valid
}
else 
{
    echo "Invalid password, please re-try";   
}
}
 else
{

echo "Enter your password";    
}
}

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if ( usernameValidation($username) == true AND   passwordValidation($password) == true )
{
 // PDO Query (SELECT ...)
}
```

Comment: Hello Amitesh, your script give the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Change your last if condition to the code below:

```
if ( usernameValidation($_POST['username']) == true AND passwordValidation($_POST['password']) == true )
{

}
```

In your functions only use the variables `$username` and `$password` and not(!) `$_POST['username']` and `$_POST['password']`

Comment: Hi Arlind, can you explain please why we should not use $_['foo'] in function?

Comment: Because you are passing the $_POST['foo'] to the function by parameter. so the value of $_POST['username'] is saved into $username

Answer (score 0):

You defined `$username` and `$password`, it is `$_POST['username']` and `$_POST['password']`. And you can also make a function without parameters. By making these changes your problem will be solved.